# Getting undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass but only on Sunday

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a rough time scratching my head with this one. I have A task class. Tasks can be repeated each day of the week. I have a handlers class that are assigned tasks. I'm currently working on a dashboard to show handlers what tasks they have today depending on the day of the week.

In my handler model:

```
def todays_walks
    # Sunday
    if Time.now.wday == 0
        Task.where('handler_id = ? AND start_time <= ? AND tasktype_id = 1 AND repeat_sunday = ?', id, Time.now.beginning_of_day, true)
    end

    # Monday
    if Time.now.wday == 1
        Task.where('handler_id = ? AND start_time <= ? AND tasktype_id = 1 AND repeat_monday = ?', id, Time.now.beginning_of_day, true)
    end

    # Tuesday
    if Time.now.wday == 2
        Task.where('handler_id = ? AND start_time <= ? AND tasktype_id = 1 AND repeat_tuesday = ?', id, Time.now.beginning_of_day, true)
    end

    # Wednesday
    if Time.now.wday == 3
        Task.where('handler_id = ? AND start_time <= ? AND tasktype_id = 1 AND repeat_wednesday = ?', id, Time.now.beginning_of_day, true)
    end

    # Thursday
    if Time.now.wday == 4
        Task.where('handler_id = ? AND start_time <= ? AND tasktype_id = 1 AND repeat_thursday = ?', id, Time.now.beginning_of_day, true)
    end

    # Friday
    if Time.now.wday == 5
        Task.where('handler_id = ? AND start_time <= ? AND tasktype_id = 1 AND repeat_friday = ?', id, Time.now.beginning_of_day, true)
    end

    # Saturday
    if Time.now.wday == 6
        Task.where('handler_id = ? AND start_time >= ? AND tasktype_id = 1 AND repeat_saturday = ?', id, Time.now.beginning_of_day, true)
    end
  end
```

Then in my view:

```
<h2>Your Day</h2>
<h3>Pups to walk:</h3>

<% if @handler.todays_walks.empty? %>
    <p>You have no dogs to walk today.</p>
<% else %>
    <%= render :partial => 'admin_shared/dashboard_pup', :collection => @handler.todays_walks.pup, :as => :pup %>
<% end %>
```

If I force any day of the week except for Sunday, it works. I imagine that this is somehow because Sunday evaluates to 0? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this doesn't work for you, but I would start from a quick refactoring to make this method much more DRY. Try this:

```
def todays_walks
  days = ["sunday","monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday"]
  return Task.where("handler_id = ? AND start_time <= ? AND tasktype_id = 1 AND repeat_#{days[Time.now.wday]} = ?", id, Time.now.beginning_of_day, true)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... Just a 'duh' moment. The model wasn't actually returning the objects. It worked on other days because they had repeat tasks.

So to fix, in the models:

```
if Time.now.wday == 0
  return Task.where('handler_id = ? AND start_time <= ? AND tasktype_id = 1 AND repeat_sunday = ?', id, Time.now.beginning_of_day, true)
end
```